# Is there an extensible IDE that allow customizing visual components?

Tags: ide

Hey guys, I wanna ask if there is an IDE to which i can customize/add custom visual components to the toolbox and define the behavior, properites .. etc of these components ?

Comment: please clarify are you looking to customize the UI of your IDE, or the UI of the application you are developing *in* your IDE.

Comment: @ Down voter : I am just curious what's bad about my question ?

Comment: @ scunliffe: It's something like the Toolbox of Visual Studio where you can drag and drop components to the stage and adjust properties for them. My purpose is much simpler though, I am not making a GUI builder, just a toolbox and a visual feedback in the form of a list of the added components. I can manage the part of visual feedback but I need to be able to define some tools in the toolbox and be able to edit them using properties box later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is the classical extensible tooling platform: http://eclipse.org

Comment: I am using eclipse already for all my development task. Would you please give me a starting point to achieve my purpose (adding toolbox components that can be edited with properties box and so on ?)

Comment: @Lettuce There are lots of different frameworks in Eclipse land, but from what you describe, GMF might be a thing to look into: http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/GMF_Tutorial If it is not quite what you are looking for look around on the wiki or try the custom search (upper right corner) at http://eclipse.org

Answer (score 0):

Delphi can do this.

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi

Comment: @ Pelle ten Cate: Do you mean Embarcadero Delphi ?

Comment: Look at the URL, and find the answer. Please.

Comment: The comment was before you added the link. Thanx i will have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans has this ability.